C++ virtual function not overriding
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class character {
private:
public:
  character(string n, int h, int a){
  }
  virtual int getHealth() = 0;
  virtual int getAttack() = 0;
  virtual string getName() = 0;
  virtual void updateHealth() = 0;
  virtual void updateAttack(int a) = 0;
  virtual void attackCharacter(character &b) = 0;
  virtual void print() = 0;
};
class entity : public character {
private:
string name;
int health;
int attack;
public:
  entity(string n, int h, int a) : character(n, h, a) {
    n = name; h = health; a = attack;
  }
  void updateAttack(int a) override { attack = a; }
  void attackCharacter(character &b) override { b.updateHealth(); b.getHealth(); }
  int getHealth() override { return health; }
  string getName() override { return name; }
  virtual void print() override {cout<<name<<" "<<health<<endl;}
  int getAttack() override { return attack; }
 void updateHealth() override { health = health - attack; }
};

#include <iostream>
#include "character.h"
using namespace std;

int main() {
   character* player = new entity("Player", 50, 5);
   entity* enemy = new entity("Enemy", 50, 5);
   player->print();
   enemy->print();
  }

Output is 0 instead of being overriden from the pure virtual statements. Is there something that I am missing that is causeing it to not be overriden? I am using the class characters to define the variables and trying to redefine them in the subclass entity

n = name; h = health; a = attack; this looks backwards. You would've noticed this if you used your debugger.

The function is overridden. It cannot possibly be not overridden. It just prints something you don't anticipate.

In C++ unlearn to use new/delete, use std::make_unique instead std;:unique_ptr<character> player = std::make_unique<entity>("Player",50,5);. This will avoid memory leaks like you currently have in your example. And stop using using namespace std;

The issue is in the entity constructor. You are assigning the values of n, h, and a to the member variables name, health, and attack, respectively, instead of initializing them.
Your constructor should look like this:
entity(string n, int h, int a)
  : character(n, h, a), name(n), health(h), attack(a) {}


This should fix all your issues and contain some learning points for you as well (the main issue was your baseclass having a constructor, which it shouldn't have) :
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <memory> // for std::unique_ptr
#include <string_view>

//using namespace std; // <== do NOT use this

class character
{
public:
    virtual ~character() = default; // <== you have to have a virtual destructor

    // do NOT declare ANY constructors in a pure virtual base class
    //  character(string n, int h, int a)
    //  {
    //  }

    virtual int getHealth() const noexcept = 0; // fix const correctness
    virtual int getAttack() const noexcept = 0;
    virtual const std::string_view getName() const noexcept = 0;
    virtual void updateHealth() = 0;
    virtual void updateAttack(int a) = 0;
    virtual void attackCharacter(character& b) = 0;
    // virtual void print() = 0; // printing is not a character's responsibility
};

class entity : public character
{
public:
    entity(const std::string& n, int h, int a) : // learn to pass classes by (const) reference
        name{ n },
        health{ h },
        attack{ a }
    {
        // NEVER initialize member variables in the constructor body
        // you will do double work, because the members will already
        // be initialized before you  enter the body 
        // (just not with the correct values)
    }

    void updateAttack(int a) override
    {
        attack = a;
    }

    void attackCharacter(character& b) override
    {
        b.updateHealth();
        b.getHealth();
    }

    int getHealth() const noexcept override
    {
        return health;
    }

    const std::string_view getName() const noexcept override
    {
        return name;
    }

    int getAttack() const noexcept override
    {
        return attack;
    }

    void updateHealth() override
    {
        health = health - attack;
    }

private:
    std::string name;
    int health;
    int attack;
};

// printing (or better outputting to a stream)
// should be done like this
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const character& c) 
{
    out << "Name: " << c.getName() << "\n";
    out << "Health: " << c.getHealth() << "\n";
    out << "Attack: " << c.getAttack() << "\n";
    return out;
}

int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<character> player = std::make_unique<entity>("Player", 50, 5);
    std::unique_ptr<entity> enemy = std::make_unique<entity>("Enemy", 30, 3);   
    
    std::cout << *player << "\n";
    std::cout << *enemy << "\n";

    // when the unique_ptr's are destroyed they will also cleanup
    // the allocated memory
}

